# Mock object in jest with eslint

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, eslint

Suppose I have the following code

```
export function myFunction(user) {
    return transform(user);
)
```

I have created a `__tests__` folder, and inside it I created a `__mocks__` folder with *user.mock.ts*

which has

```
export const user = { id: 1, name: "John" }
```

Now in my `__test__` folder, I have user.spec.ts

```
import { user } from './__mocks__/user.mock';

describe('user', () => {
  it('should map user correctly', () => {
    const expected = { id: 1, name: "John" } 
    const result = myFunction(user);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

I have the following eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "eslint-plugin-jest"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:jest/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
  }
}
```

I get the following error

> *Mocks should not be manually imported from a **mocks** directory. Instead use `jest.mock` and import from the original module
> path.eslintjest/no-mocks-import*

Comment: Why is that a *mock*? That seems to be static test data, the implementation doesn't import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism of using a specially-named directory called `__mocks__` is a way of jest being able to auto-detect mocks for packages (not as a place to put code you plan to run explicitly).

Files from this folder would never be explicitly imported by you in your code as part of a test.

So if you just use a normal folder name for your case, and don't cross-wire with the jest convention, then you should be able to eliminate the error.

By contrast if you wanted to actually mock an existing package (like replace `fetch` with your own version of `fetch`) then see https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules for how you would construct a file e.g. called `__mocks__/fetch.ts` to swap out the real implementation of fetch for one which fakes its behaviour. That is the only thing the specially-named directory should be used for.